# Objective C++ OpenGL implementation

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, opengl, objective-c++

first question on the site, so I'm sorry if I do anything unconventional. I decided to post a minimal amount of my actual code and rather links to the what tutorials I followed because I'd be post a good amount of files. For those that bear with me, you have no idea how much I appreciate it.

I am currently developing an cross platform engine in C++ for graphics rendering, more of a fun project than a necessity. My main development platform is my Macbook Pro, so I decided the first part of the engine I would like to implement is the Mac port. Because I want the application to behave like a native app, I decided I wanted to use Cocoa for the front end.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.dbiesiada.com/blog/2013/04/simple-skeleton-framework-for-cocoa-osx-opengl-application/) and it worked nicely with the demo that came with it, as well as the first tutorial on lazyfoo's website. I have done tutorials over a year ago, but I wanted to check and make sure I knew how to implement what I learned a while back.

It wasn't until I got to [the second tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/02_matrices_and_coloring_polygons/index.php) that I had issues. So editing the tut01_renderer class, I so far have added one variable, the integer gColorMode variable used by lazyfoo in his tutorial for comparison in his render method. I have attempted to initialize gColorMode to 0 (cyan) in the header, the tut01renderer init method, or both. Finally, in the the tut01renderer render method, I put an if/else statement:

```
    if(gColorMode == 0)
    {

    //Solid Cyan
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glColor3f( 0.f, 1.f, 1.f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glEnd();
    }
    else
    {
        //RYGB Mix
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glColor3f( 1.f, 0.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glColor3f( 1.f, 1.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glColor3f( 0.f, 1.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glColor3f( 0.f, 0.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f( -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glEnd();
    }
```

This brings about 3 scenarios when I run, and no matter how I initialized the gColorMode, each of the 3 happen.

1) It crashes to either malloc error, editing an objecting that was freed OR bad access error in assembly.
2) Shows the cyan square like it should
3) Shows the multi square!

I have even made gColorMode a constant and it STILL sometimes shows the multi square or crashes!

So my question is if I am doing anything wrong or unheard of. Am I allowed to have an if/else statement in the render method? The original skeletal code demo used variables, but not if/else statements? Is there something about Objective C++ that makes what I am trying to do impossible? Or is something else?

(Lastly, I will gladly reimplement this is in plain C and objective C if anyone knows of a good enough tutorial. Obvious my engine is in C++, but it might be easier overall to go with this approach.)

Comment: I suggest quickly moving away from the old and deprecated OpenGL functionality you're using (called "fixed function pipeline") and reading this excellent tutorial on modern OpenGL programming: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach, it should work. If you want to I don't mind taking a quick look at your project. However as Victor Sand said it's recommended that you move on from the old OpenGL style. I find arcsynthesis's tutorial a bit confusing from a mac perspective. http://www.reddit.com/r/opengl sidebar on the right has a few great tutorial's and you can check those out.

Comment: There must've been something wrong with the header because I was able to redo the program in an entirely new project file and it worked. Typically I get these random errors when I have header errors. I still can't find the particular error in question, but luckily I have a working program. Thanks for the help everyone! (Definitely working on learning GLSL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any control structures you want (if/else, for loops etc) when calling OpenGL functions, as long as you don't mess up the order. E.g. for each `glBegin()` there must be a corresponding `glEnd()`, and `glVertex` must be called between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. The code you posted looks fine. Assuming there's an error in your code it must be somewhere else.

I would set `gColorMode` to 0 and set a breakpoint where you draw the multicolored quad. Find out why it's taking that path. You could also set a data breakpoint which triggers when `gColorMode` changes. If that doesn't tell you anything, step through your code with a debugger and find out which function call causes this "bad access error".

I don't know what else to tell you without being able to look at more code.